# Perl: file not recognized

Tags: perl

I have this file

```
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 user user      32 Sep 20 15:43 SingletonLock -> user.hostname.com-22222
```

I need perl recognizes that file and get its size, What command could I use for this?

I have tried:

```
my $size = (lstat("/home/user/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock -> user.hostname.com-22222"))[7];
print $size;
```

but the variable is empty and `$!` is `No such file or directory`

Answer (score 3):

The [`stat`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html) function?  Or you might need [`lstat`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/lstat.html) to get the link information, or [`readlink`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readlink.html) to read the name that the symbolic link points to.

Example of `stat` and `lstat` working:

```
$ echo "Petunia" > user.hostname.com-22222
$ ln -s user.hostname.com-22222 SingletonLock
$ ls -l user.* Singl*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 jleffler  staff  23 Sep 26 20:24 SingletonLock -> user.hostname.com-22222
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff   8 Sep 26 20:24 user.hostname.com-22222
$ cat stat.pl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @names = ( "user.hostname.com-22222", "SingletonLock" );

foreach my $file (@names)
{
    my ($dev,$ino,$mode,$nlink,$uid,$gid,$rdev,$size,
            $atime,$mtime,$ctime,$blksize,$blocks)
        = lstat $file;
    printf "lstat: %2d (%.5o) - %s\n", $size, $mode, $file;
    ($dev,$ino,$mode,$nlink,$uid,$gid,$rdev,$size,
            $atime,$mtime,$ctime,$blksize,$blocks)
        = stat $file;
    printf "stat:  %2d (%.5o) - %s\n", $size, $mode, $file;
}
$ perl stat.pl
lstat:  8 (100644) - user.hostname.com-22222
stat:   8 (100644) - user.hostname.com-22222
lstat: 23 (120755) - SingletonLock
stat:   8 (100644) - SingletonLock
$
```

Comment: I already have tried with `stat` and `lstat` but don't get any result.

Comment: Waddya mean? How did you try? How do you know you didn't get a result?  Which did you try?

Comment: On error, `stat` and `lstat` return an empty list and assign an error message to `$!`. Is that what you get? What does `$!` contain?

Comment: I have tried `my $size = (lstat("/home/user/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock -> user.hostname.com-22222"))[7]; print $size;` but the variable is empty

Comment: `$! = No such file or directory`

Comment: The name of the file is `/home/user/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock`; `ls` adds the `-> user.hostname.com-22222` to indicate that it is a symlink and that it is a symlink to `user.hostname.com-22222`.

Answer (score 0):

Give only file name to lstat

```
my $size = (lstat("/home/user/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock"))[7];
```

If you want to get only size of the file you can use `-s` option in perl

```
print -s "/home/user/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock";
```

or

```
$filesize = -s $filename;
```